# error with `locate(p, lt, li, start)` function when insert weighted point in regular triangulation

Tags: compiler-errors, cgal

I am trying to refactor an old code that uses CGAL3.9, using CGAL5.6.
I have an error when using the `insert` function with a weighted point in a `regular triangulation`.

my insert function is

```
Vertex_handle Scene::insert_vertex(const Point& point,
                                   const FT weight,
                                   const unsigned index)
{
    Weighted_point wp(point, weight);
    Vertex_handle vertex = m_rt.insert(wp); // <-- error

    if (vertex->get_index() != -1)
        return Vertex_handle();

    vertex->set_index(index);
    return vertex;
}
```

the error said that the `locate(p, lt, li, start)` function used by the `insert(p)` function cannot be found.

In this code, the Kernel used is a `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` and `m_rt` is a custom triangulation `CTriangulation<Regular_triangulation>` with Regular_triangulation a `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_2<Kernel, TDS>`.

My build message note that it can finds a `locate` function but `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Weighted_point’ {aka ‘const CGAL::Weighted_point_2<CGAL::Epick>’} to ‘const Point&’ {aka ‘const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&’}`.

Is there something I need to add / change from the code using CGAL3.9 to make it works with CGAL5.6 ?

Initial code used `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_filtered_traits_2<Kernel>` to define the `Weighted_point` and it is now deprecated.
I now use the `Kernel::Weighted_point_2` to define it.

I saw in the documentation that there is explicit conversion between `Point_2` and `Weighted_point_2` and I don't understand why it doesn achieve to use it.

Comment: Can you please explicit what is `TDS`? The `Point` type defined in the vertex type needs to be a weighted point.

Comment: `TDS` is a `CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<MVb, MFb>` with `MVb` a custom `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_vertex_base_2<Kernel>` and `MFb` a custom `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_face_base_2<Kernel>`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the `Point` type define in the vertex" ? I have `Point` and `Weighted_point` types coming from the `Kernel` and the `Regular_triangulation` in which I insert a weighted point is also define from the `Kernel`.

Comment: As you have seen the `locate()` function in the class `CGAL::Triangulation_2` (the base of `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_2`) takes a `Point` type. This `Point` type is defined using the TDS's vertex class : `typedef typename Tds::Vertex::Point         Point;` (in `CGAL::Triangulation_2`). The error you get seems to indicate that your `Point` type in the vertex class is `K::Point_2` and not `K::Weighted_point_2` thus you have this incompatibility.

What is the `Point` type defined in your custom `CGAL::Regular_triangulation_vertex_base_2` class? It needs to be equal to `K::Weighted_point_2`.

Comment: You've got the point (literally). Thanks a lot